# Find 'Most Similar' Items in Table by Foreign Key

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a child table with a number of charact/value pairs for a given 'material' (MaterialID).  Any material can have a number of charact values and may have several of the same name (see id's 2,3).

The table has a large number of records (8+ million).  What I'm trying to do is **find the materials that are the most similar to a supplied material**.  That is, when I supply a MaterialID, I would like an ordered list of the most similar other materials (those with the most matching charact/value pairs).

I've done some research but, I may be missing some key terms or just not conceptualizing the problem correctly.

Any hints as to how to go about this would be very much appreciated.

```
ID  MaterialID  Charact             Value
1   1           ROT_DIR             CCW
2   1           SPECIAL_FEATURE     CATALOG_CP
3   1           SPECIAL_FEATURE     CHROME
4   1           SCHEDULE            80
5   2           BEARING_TYPE        SB
6   2           SCHEDULE            80
7   3           ROT_DIR             CCW
8   3           SPECIAL_FEATURE     CATALOG_HSB
9   3           BEARING_TYPE        SP
10  4           NDE_STYLE           W_FAN
11  4           BEARING_TYPE        SB
12  4           ROT_DIR             CW*
```

Comment: Do you want that `1` | `ROT_DIR` | `CCW` is right above `3` | `ROT_DIR` | `CCW` ? Or what is the result you want to have?

Comment: The result would be a list of MaterialID's that are most similar to the MaterialID that I supply.  That is; if I supply MaterialID = 1, the results would be an ordered list of other MaterialID's that most match the Charact/Value pairs of MaterialID = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a self join:

```
select t.materialid, count(*) as nummatches
from t join
     t tmat
     on t.Charact = tmat.Charact and t.value = tmat.value
where tmat.materialid = @MaterialId
group by t.materialid
order by nummatches desc;
```

Notes:

- You might want to remove the specified material, by adding `where t.MaterialId <> tmat.MaterialId` to the `where` clause.
- If you want all materials, then make the join a `left join` and move the `where` condition to the `on` clause.
- If you want only one material with the most matches, use `select top 1`.
- If you want all materials with the most matches when there are ties, use `select top (1) with ties.